# Where is Slovak keyboard QWERTZ

Tags: keyboard

I can not find a QWERTZ keyboard for slovak language input. In the place of Z there is a "Y", how can I get a QWERTZ keyboard? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open System Settings -> Keyboard -> Text Entry, on the right corner of the left part, choose the keyboard icon, choose Slovak from the table. Delete Sloavk (QWERTY). Done!

Comment: In my case, I had to reboot system to apply new layout