# How to add/configure QWERTZ keyboard layout on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard-layout

I am trying to add QWERTZ Slovak keyboard layout, but it is not listed under Region & Language -> Input Sources. I find QWERTZ layout quite standard in my region. Is it possible to install it or is there any other way how to configure the keyboard?

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/699755/where-is-slovak-keyboard-qwertz

Comment: @Terrance Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. Layout is still QWERTY

Comment: @Terrance it worked, but I had to reboot PC, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 18.04 select Slovak only not Slovak (something) it is QWERTZ.
[image: choose]

[image: kbd]

after selecting close the settings windows.
and
**Reboot**

Comment: Well, it didn't worked just by switching the input. I had to reboot PC and then the layout was applied :) Thanks

Comment: @madox2 Edited as suggested. Thanks.