# Ubuntu 22.04: Invalid keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, keyboard-layout

I have only a single input source with a **QWERTZ layout**. This layout is used for all windows. Yet mysteriously, I get a completely different layout (**English QWERTY**) registered nowhere (randomly, out of the blue).

To fix this, I must create a new input source (it can be any layout) and remove it again.

Even more bizarre is that this wrong layout only affects some applications (*Chrome, VSCODE*), but others behave correctly (*Terminal*).

I have yet to find a cause (some keystroke combinations, maybe) or permanent solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add/configure QWERTZ keyboard layout on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122504/how-to-add-configure-qwertz-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Sorry but no. I have the right layout, it just randomly changes to a non-existing layout.